# goMap jquery how to add a click event to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

what i want is to make the map clickable and link me to the address that i want 
the code that i have now is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate googlemaps                  
    jQuery("#' . $block_id . '-map").goMap({ address: "' . $address . '",
            zoom: 15,
            navigationControl: true, 
            maptype: "ROADMAP",
            draggable: false, zoomControl: false, scrollwheel: true, disableDragging: true,

            markers: [
                { "address" : "' . $address . '" }
            ] 
    }); 
});
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        ...
});
```

You can read more about click events over [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#UIEvents).